# Using Variables from a .csv file to use as text in a .kv file

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

Im writing a little mobile App with kivy and python.
Currently im completely working without the .kv extension because i dont know how to achieve this:

In the future i want to implement language support. basically i have a .csv file, that has all the Variable Names for each language in different columns

I want to use these names in the .kv App. Do you have an idea how i could implement that without doing everything manually?

```
    self.b1 = Button(text=csv_lang.loc[1, self.lang], font_name="Frutiger", font_size="25",
                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 0.7])
    self.b1.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
    self.categorie.add_widget(self.b1)
    self.b2 = Button(text=csv_lang.loc[2, self.lang], font_name="Frutiger", font_size="25",
                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 0.7])
    self.categorie.add_widget(self.b2)
    self.b3 = Button(text=csv_lang.loc[3, self.lang], font_name="Frutiger", font_size="25",
                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 0.7])
    self.categorie.add_widget(self.b3)
```

Sincerly Pascal